# First indent is shorter than it should be

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am using `\paragraph{}` at the beginning of chapter. All my paragraphs are intended automatically but first indent is always little bit shorter than others (I mean that white space).
Does anyone experienced this problem before? I have no idea what's wrong

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, includefoot]{geometry} %total={17cm,25cm},
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\def\baselinestretch{1.2}\normalsize

\chapter*{First one}

\paragraph{}
\bigskip

{\bf First} - aaaaaa\\

{\bf Second} - bbbbbb\\

{\bf Third} - ccccccc\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Here it is. I let there all the packages I am using in case they cause the problem.

Comment: Unrelated note: You shouldn't use `\bf`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516). It looks like you're creating a list, and there are list environments for that, see e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures.

Comment: don't use a double backslash to end a paragraph.  some good reasons are given in the answers to the question [Why gap + indent after \\ and return](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32395/579).

Answer (score 2):

`\paragraph` is a sectioning command, just as `\chapter`, `\section` etc, it is not intended for starting a new paragraph -- an empty line does that (or `\par`).

In the standard classes, there is no indentation of the first paragraph of a chapter/section (why should there be?), but the `\paragraph` command adds some space. Hence, what you're seeing is not paragraph indentation, but space added by the  `\paragraph` command.

If you really want to indent the first paragraph, use `indentfirst` as mentioned by Mario, and remove the `\paragraph{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
First paragraph. Not indented.

Second paragraph, indented.

\paragraph{Lower level heading}     \texttt{paragraph} is below \texttt{subsection} (and \texttt{subsubsection}).

\section{Second section}

\paragraph{} \texttt{paragraph} used wrongly, note extra space.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Seems I didn't understand how paragraph works.

Comment: @user2306381 Glad it helped. Please accept my answer, by clicking the check mark to the left. This marks the question as answered, and awards some reputation points to both myself and you. See our [welcome page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for more information about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `indentfirst` package by David Carlisle (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst))
and then call it on your preamble:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Hello.

This is my second paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't make any change.

Comment: Did you take away all the `\paragrahp{}` ?  It should work...